# Cat walked across keyboard, jwplayer keyboard shortcuts disabled

Tags: jwplayer

So my cat ran across my keyboard while watching a MyCloud hosted video, and now my JWPlayer (for MyCloud server) keyboard shortcuts are all disabled. There was briefly an on-screen dialog box about it, but I can't seem to replicate what the cat pushed to get it to come back up.
Any assistance would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

To bring up the menu to re-enable keyboard shortcuts: On any JW Player, right click and select the menu option labeled `Keyboard Shortcuts`. You should see a toggle labeled "Disabled", click that to re-enable them.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. This happens to me all the time!!!

Comment: While this suggestion didn't work for me (right clicking on the JWplayer window fails to bring up any options at all!), a refresh of my Firefox browser (complete with default configurations, all add-ins removed and later reinstalled) did solve the issue for me.